# in c++, the fastest way to convert a positive number to 1 and negative to 0

Tags: c++, performance, microbenchmark

I'm writing this code to make a candlestick chart and I want a red box if the open price for the day is greater than the close. I also want the box to be green if the close is higher than the open price.

```
if(open > close) {
    boxColor = red;
} else {
    boxColor = green;
}
```

Pseudo code is easier than an English sentence for this.

So I wrote this code first and then tried to benchmark it but I don't know how to get meaningful results.

```
for(int i = 0; i < history.get().close.size(); i++) {
    auto open = history->open[i];
    auto close = history->close[i];
    int red = ((int)close - (int)open) >> ((int)sizeof(close) * 8);
    int green = ((int)open - (int)close) >> ((int)sizeof(close) * 8);
    gl::color(red,green,0);
    gl::drawSolidRect( Rectf(vec2(i - 1, open), vec2(i + 1, close)) );
}
```

This is how I tried to benchmark it. Each run just shows 2ns. My main question to the community is this:

Can I actually make it faster by using a right shift and avoid a conditional branch?

```
#include <benchmark/reporter.h>

static void BM_red_noWork(benchmark::State& state) {
    double open = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    double close = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_red_noWork);

static void BM_red_fast_work(benchmark::State& state) {
    double open = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    double close = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        int red = ((int)open - (int)close) >> sizeof(int) - 1;
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_red_fast_work);

static void BM_red_slow_work(benchmark::State& state) {
    double open = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    double close = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        int red = open > close ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_red_slow_work);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many candlesticks do you have where this has to be that performant? A billion? Remember signed numbers have a *sign bit*. If you can spin through a chart in 2ns I really doubt you've got any meaningful performance problems.

Comment: These sorts of micro-optimizations can generally be handled by the compiler.  If you are not certain if the compiler is performing them, then you can inspect the assembly using the `-S` flag in g++ and clang++.  However, if you're unsure how to even measure the effect of the optimization, then it's likely that this optimization is unnecessary and not a good use of your time.  The difference between the two algorithms is very small, and it doesn't seem like you're running this code millions of times to magnify the small differences.

Comment: Get things working correctly first before you worry about performance. Also, trust the compilers optimizer and in any case don't optimize before you've run a profiler over an optimized build and identified what the *actual* performance issues are (if any).

Comment: Have you tried `x >= 0`

Comment: I think @M.M has the right idea here. Do the simplest possible thing and see how well the compiler handles it. If you're really up against the wall here, forget the CPU, it'll never be fast enough, and instead do this on a GPU. A high-end GPU can do several *thousand* of these ops in parallel.

Comment: @tadman, The CPU is much faster for single threaded operation than the GPU, that is probably poor advice given the code example and the state usage case.  However, I agree with doing the simplest possible thing.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I see OpenGL calls here, so using a shader to compute these bits is not entirely outrageous. A little GLSL code could do this in a snap. In fact, I think skipping the conversion part and instead using a shader to draw the whole chart is probably the fastest approach overall. It would be basically zero effort to compute the color of the sticks.

Comment: That is fair, but if we're using GL calls anyway, then the time to perform that call would completely wash out any gain from this code anyway.

Comment: For large amounts of data I certainly agree with tadman. I more familar with DirectX but both are essentially same. In fact if you have all your data to be sorted to positive and negative, why this is no different than culling polygons. So if you have a million points to sort per second, the gpu can easily do this and is no different than what it is already doing. In dxd12 you can use compute shaders too, I guess similar to cuda.

Comment: @tadman Yea, I'm getting started with cinder so I'm trying to draw boxes with the library's built in function. I think you are right though, I can try to draw the whole thing with a shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, the compiler will do these optimizations for you.  Here is a minimal compilable example:

```
int main() {
  volatile int a = 42;
  if (a <= 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The `volatile` is simply to prevent optimizations from "knowing" the value of `a` and instead it forces it to be read.

This was compiled with the command `g++ -O3 -S test.cpp` and it produces a file named test.s

Inside test.s is the assembly generated by the compiler (pardon AT&T syntax):

```
movl    $42, -4(%rsp)
movl    -4(%rsp), %eax
testl   %eax, %eax
setg    %al
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

As you can see, it is branchless.  It uses `testl` to set a flag if the number is `<= 0` and then reads that value using `setg`, moves it back into the proper register, then finally it returns.

It should be noted, at this was adapted from your code.  A much better way to write this is simply:

```
int main() {
  volatile int a = 42;
  return a > 0;
}
```

It also generates the same assembly.

This is likely to be better than anything readable you could write directly in C++.  For instance your code (hopefully corrected for bit arithmetic errors):

```
int main() {
  volatile int a = 42;
  return ~(a >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)) & 1;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
movl    $42, -4(%rsp)
movl    -4(%rsp), %eax
notl    %eax
shrl    $31, %eax
ret
```

Which is indeed, very slightly smaller.  But it's not significantly faster.  Especially not when you have a GL call right next to it.  I'd rather spend 1-3 additional cycles to get readable code, rather than have to scratch my head wondering what my coworker (or me from 6 months ago, which is essentially the same thing) did.

EDIT: I should be remarked that the compiler also optimized the bit arithmetic I wrote, because I wrote it less well than I could have.  The assembly is actually: `(~a) >> 31` which is equivalent to the `~(a >> 31) & 1` that I wrote (at least in most implementations with an unsigned integer, see comments for details).

Comment: Actually, your code has implementation defined behavior (right shifting a possibly negative number). In most implementations, `(~a)>>31` is not equivalent with `~(a>>31)&1`, because right shifting a negative number usually uses sign extension.

Comment: "I'd rather spend 1-3 additional cycles to get readable code, rather than have to scratch my head wondering": You can have both. Create a function for this, which has a descriptive name. Or just put a comment there explaining the purpose and working mechanism of it. But of course, in this example, this optimization is meaningless, because a GL call is much more expensive, than this simple test (I agree with you in this part)

Comment: @geza, You're completely correct, I was being a bit sloppy and mixing my C++ and assembly.  The `shrl` of course does a logical shift, so I've stuck a note in the answer to help clear up the confusion.

Comment: In response to your second bit.  I'm not even really convinced that the bit arithmetic code is actually faster.  It's CPU dependent I believe.  None of the instructions involved should take much longer than a cycle, except perhaps `shrl`.  Moreover, both codes have a pipeline dependency (Read after Write), so it's hard to say with is actually faster.  I gave the edge to the bit arithmetic, but that mostly was just for the sake of argument.

Comment: Bearing that in mind, even a friendly named function call can be problematic if I'm in the middle of debugging, because that's a context switch.  I'd rather keep the code where I can see it.  It seems extremely silly to break `return a>0` into its own function.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't say which version is faster :) I've just said, if one can get 1-3 cycles faster code, then maybe he/she should do it (if it helps performance - which is not the case here, I'm sure), even if the code becomes a little bit cryptic. Comments/function names can help. But yeah, for this simple thing, maybe it is overkill to have a separate function, so basically I agree with you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the awesome explanation. I was really hoping to learn from the answers to this question and I'm really happy that I got a quality answer and quality conversation. I did not know that right shift on a negative number is undefined behavior. I don't understand what `~(a>>31)&1` is supposed to do. It seems like for a positive or negative number you would have 0xxx or 1xxx shifted right with sign extension to give you 0000 or 1111. Then you flip all of the bits and & it with 0001. So I have 1111 and 0001...

Comment: 0000 & 0001 = 0000, 1111 & 0001 = 0001 ;)